# UINavigationBar Dont Appear

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

The UINavigationBar From self.navigationController does not appear. I set the top bar in the IB to 'Black Navigation Bar', it shows on the IB but still not appear on the device.

I already tried:

> self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
>   self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;

What is happening?

Comment: We need to see a little more code please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple terms, the system isn't showing the navigation bar because there is no reason for it to, as you haven't wrapped you're view controller in a navigation controller, which is the context in which navigation bars are typically used.

To do this, select your view controller and click `Window` > `Embed in` > `Navigation Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialized and the viewcontrollers are pushed into the navigation stack and displayed.Navigation bar is part of navigation controller.If navigationcontroller not initialized and added nav bar wont be visible